# Is it possible to don't include javascript files that are previously included to the system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I want to include my javascript file if they are not include previously. Is it possible?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't you know if they were included? I mean, you can inspect the page and see if the script is loaded, if not, then include it?

Comment: No it is a dynamic page. all the pages are load into one div.

Comment: Don't marked as duplicate. This is not it

Comment: Hey you can check out this really cool tool called browserify

Comment: Still, even as a dynamic page you should know whether a script is loaded. It has to be written somewhere in the code, if you want it to be dynamic why not make a logic that checks what page is being loaded and then include the scripts the page need?